# Selecting every Nth row per user in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, window-functions, row-number

I was using this SQL statement:

```
SELECT "dateId", "userId", "Salary" 
FROM (
   SELECT *, 
          (row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "userId", "dateId"))%2 AS rn 
   FROM user_table
 ) sa 
 WHERE sa.rn=1 
   AND "userId" = 789 
   AND "Salary" > 0;
```

But every time the table gets new rows the result of the query is different.
Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to tell us what you want to do and what a "new row" looks like, especially the "userId" and "dateId" you use for ORDER BY in the window function.

Comment: I want to optimize this query to give me the same results everytime I'm updating the table. dateId - just decimal replresentation of the date

Comment: Changed "dateId" changes the sort order in your window function. Hence, changes in the result are to be expected.

Comment: How can I avoid this? I was thinking that adding "dateId" to the bottom of the table shouldn't affect the sort order...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `("dateId", "userId")` is unique and new rows always have a bigger (later) `dateId`.

#### After some comments:

What I **think** you need:

```
SELECT "dateId", "userId", "Salary"
FROM (
   SELECT "dateId", "userId", "Salary"
         ,(row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY "userId"   -- either this
                              ORDER BY "dateId")) % 2 AS rn
   FROM   user_table
   WHERE  "userId" = 789                              -- ... or that
   ) sub
WHERE  sub.rn = 1
AND    "Salary" > 0;
```

Notice the [**`PARTITION BY`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/tutorial-window.html). This way you skip every second `dateId` for each `userId`, and additional (later) rows don't change the selection so far.

Also, as long as you are selecting rows for a ***single*** `userId` (`WHERE "userId" = 789`), pull the predicate into the subquery, achieving the same effect (stable selection for a single user). You don't need both.

The `WHERE` clause in the subquery only works for a single user, `PARTITION BY` works for any number of users in one query.

<sub>Is that it? Is it?

<sub>They should give me "detective" badge for this.

<sub>Seriously.</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My "dateId" is a foreign key(unique). I'm going to try with some "sequenceId" but doubt that it will make a difference

Comment: "dateId" may be unique in the referenced table, but can still be referenced multiple times in user_table. You are aware of that, right?
Try my little test for dupes, then you know for sure.

Comment: I run the test and got nothing in results. The way I created the table is that particular user+ particular date can only exist once in the db

Comment: @TimGL: Can you tell me what the intention behind this code is: `(row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "userId", "dateId"))%2 AS rn ... WHERE sa.rn=1` I suggest you edit your question with that information. I suspect I can solve your problem, once I understand what this is supposed to achieve. Also, I still wonder if my assumption about "userId" is correct (see start of my answer).

Comment: Brandstetter: You are right about "userId" - it is incremental.

Comment: The reason I'm doing %2 is because I need every 3rd record for my calculations(stddev).Ultimately I want to be able to query table with different time frames.I want to get 1,3,5,7 rows, then 3 days table gets updates(+8,9,10) and the next time I'm running this query I should be able to get 1,3,5,7,9 rows and not 2,4,6,8,10

Comment: You are aware that %2 gives every **2nd** row? Try this demo: `select x, x%2 from generate_series(1,20,1) x`. I am having a hard time to understand the rest of your comment.

Comment: It is every 2nd row but every 3rd day:) I'm sorry for the broken English here. What I meant was that I need my results be the same no matter how many rows I'm querying.

Answer (score 0):

No that seems to be OK.
You have new rows, those rows change the old rows to appear on different position after sorting.

Answer (score 0):

If someone insert a new row with a userId below 789 the order will change.
For example, if you have:

```
userId rn
 1      1
 4      0
 5      1
 6      0
```

and you insert a row with userId = 2, the rn will change:

```
userId rn
 1      1
 2      0
 4      1
 5      0
 6      1
```

In order to select every Nth row you need a column with a sequence or a timestamp.

Comment: This is my table:
"dateId", "userId", "Salary" and every day I'm updating the table with the new date(sequence, decimal), userId stays the same and Salary changes:
 - 15234, 789, 32
 - 15237, 789, 35
 - 15238, 789, 36

dateId - is a sequence, but doesn't includet weekends and holidays.