# SELECT fixed number of rows by evenly skipping rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to write a query which returns an arbitrary sized representative sample of data. I would like to do this by only selecting n<sup>th</sup> rows where n is such that the entire result set is as close as possible to an arbitrary size.

I want this to work in cases where the result set would normally be less than the arbitrary size. In such a case, the entire result set should be returned.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518788/selecting-every-nth-row-in-postgres) which shows how to select every n<sup>th</sup> row.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT *, ((row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "time"))
               % ceil(count(*)::FLOAT / 500::FLOAT)::BIGINT) AS rn
   FROM data_raw) sa
WHERE sa.rn=0;
```

This results in the following error:

> ERROR: column "data_raw.serial" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 23

Removing the calculation for `n` like this works:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT *, (row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "time"))
              % 50 AS rn FROM data_raw) sa
LIMIT 500;
```

I also tried moving the calculation to the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT *, (row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "time")) AS rn
   FROM data_raw) sa
WHERE (sa.rn % ceil(count(*)::FLOAT / 500::FLOAT)::BIGINT)=0;
```

That too results in an error:

> ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE Position: 108

Does anyone have any ideas on either how to fix my query or a better way to do this?

I have also thought about using random numbers and probability to select rows, but I would rather do something deterministic without the possibility of clumping.

Comment: BTW, pg 9.4? You are using the beta-release?

Comment: Yes, I am using 9.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake in your first attempt is that you can't mix the aggregate function `count(*)` with the *un-aggregated* selection of rows. You can fix this by using `count()` as window-aggregate function instead:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT *, ((row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "time"))
               % ceil(count(*) OVER () / 500.0)::int) AS rn
   FROM   data_raw
   ) sub
WHERE sub.rn = 0;
```

Detailed explanation here:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied-in-php-postgresql/8242764#8242764)

[@Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27013394/939860) has a fix for your last attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You should make that calculation a subquery:

```
WHERE rn % (SELECT CEIL(COUNT(*)::FLOAT / 500:FLOAT)::BIGINT FROM data_raw) = 0
```

This way, it is no longer seen as an aggregate function, but as a scalar query.